# change the content of a span and then wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript

My problem: I have an JSON Array containing arrays, which i render into the body tag - so that it looks like this:

```
<body data-flashes="[["message","Welcome"],["error","This is working!"],["",""]]">
```

i want to do the following:

1. go each element in the outer array
2. the first element in the inner array will become the classname of a span
3. the second element in the inner array will become the text in a span
4. animate the span
5. wait 10 seconds
6. start over again

( its always the same span)
my try:

```
window.pause = ( ms ) -> (
    date = new Date()
    currentDate = null

    loop
        currentDate = new Date()
        break unless currentDate-date < ms
)
window.showFlashes = () -> (
    $.each( window.$('body').data('flashes'), () -> (
            window.$('#flash_container').attr( 'class', this[0] )
            window.$('#flash_container').text( this[1] )
            window.$('#flash_container').effect( 'pulsate' )

            alert this

            pause( 10000 )
        )
    )
)
```

this is coffeescript which rails renders into following javascript-file:

```
(function() {

  window.pause = function(ms) {
    var currentDate, date, _results;
    date = new Date();
    currentDate = null;
    _results = [];
    while (true) {
      currentDate = new Date();
      if (!(currentDate - date < ms)) {
        break;
      } else {
        _results.push(void 0);
      }
    }
    return _results;
  };

  window.showFlashes = function() {
    return $.each(window.$('body').data('flashes'), function() {
      window.$('#flash_container').attr('class', this[0]);
      window.$('#flash_container').text(this[1]);
      window.$('#flash_container').effect('pulsate');
      alert(this);
      return pause(10000);
    });
  };

  window.exit_after = function(ms) {
    var _results;
    setTimeout("return 0", ms);
    _results = [];
    while (true) {
      _results.push(ms = 1);
    }
    return _results;
  };

}).call(this);
```

now the "real" problem: as long as i have the `alert this` in the code it works fine (besides that the animation is not working). but when i remove it, the code stops working.

and my second problem is: is there a  way to get around the `pause` function? i would rather like to use `setTimeout()`, but i dont know how to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout() is the solution to all of this.

It takes two arguments, the first being a string to be executed and the second to be the delay in milliseconds from now.

To ease this, I would wrap your block of code in a function and then call this function using setTimeout(). For instance:

```
function do_stuff()
{
...
}

setTimeout("do_stuff()",10000);
```

Would mean that do_stuff() is going to be called in 10seconds time.

I hope that helps.

Comment: nope, that is how far i also got. but the timeout is the last to come in my order. so my function would be empty. and if its not clear: the contents of the array go into the same span, after each other.

Comment: So I think that I must have missed the point then.  I thought you were looking for a process that would happen every 10 seconds. How does your situation differ from this?

Comment: the first action has to be executed directly, afterwards there has to be a 10 seconds delay...

Comment: okay, i fixed it now. i used setTimeout for it. i will post later. thanks for your help :)

Comment: Using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a string is generally a bad idea due to scoping and `eval` issues, `setTimeout(do_stuff, 10000)` would be better.